# How do I go from a 3-way switch controlling my basement lights to multiple 3-way switches?

Tags: switch, multiway-switch

Currently my basement has multiple lights that are connected to a 3-way switch that can be operated from upstairs or in the basement.

I’m renovating my basement and will break it up into 3 different sections with an open floor plan.

I’d like to have 3-way switches controlling each section of the basement individually

I’m new to this and no I cannot afford an electrician right now

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: Can you turn off the breaker for the basement lights, then open up the boxes involved and post photos of their innards please?

Comment: This question needs clarification.   Do you want more switches controlling the existing lighting? Or do you want to break up the lighting into separately controlled areas.

Comment: Do you ever want to turn the basement lights *on* from upstairs?  Or only *off*?  Is the stairway part of this lighting?

Comment: " New to this"   means you should **NOT** be attempting to do this sort of rewiring.  If you can't afford an electrician then either wait, or find a friend with extensive electrical experience to show you what to do.

Comment: @georgeanderson I want to break up the lighting into separately controlled areas

Answer (score 2):

### What you're really looking for is zone control.

You still want the ability to turn *all* the basement lights on/off from the 3-way switches.  **In fact, the ability to do so is a Code requirement, since the stairwell lights *must* be on a 3-way.**  However, you want the ability to extinguish lights in areas you don't need.

So what you can do is add an additional block of switches on the "switched side" of the 3-way circuit.  That is, the side *after* the 3-way travelers.   *In other words, don't overthink it*.

The simplest way to do this, by the way, is to install lamps with pull chains.  But we can do it with real switches.

Let's start with a simple view of what a 3-way circuit *is*.  (And by the way, I strongly recommend you get colored tape and actually mark your wires these colors - because things will get really complicated if you do not!!)

[image]

Don't overthink it: don't mess with the yellows here. As things are, the "red" is on or off according to 3-way command. It branches out to your multiple, various lights including the stairwell light.    So we're going to have the "red" serve as the power input to another bank of normal (1-way) switches. They will input red "switched-hot" and output "switched, *switched* hot" to those lights you want separate control of.

Now, you can control the bunch with the 3-ways, and select which of the bunch turn on at the supplemental switches.

The stairwell light proper, since by law it must be under direct control of the 3-ways, will still get its power off the red, and will not be under a subsidiary switch.

### Is this conservation necessary?

The better thing to do might actually be say sayonara to incandescent lights, and convert to LED.  Then you won't need to worry about the electric bill.

Comment: He never said he cared about energy use.   He most likely just wants to be able to control lights in different sections (quite probably with walls in between) separately.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The whole article wasn't that, it was just a mention at the top Now bottom. But wow, I got a DV for that?? The DVer should maybe then rush over here and DV [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/190602/47125), which is *all* alternative.  So no credit for the voice of experience anticipating root causes and XY problems, eh?

Comment: @harper thanks for the help. Very detailed and easy enough for a newbie to understand. I am installing canless LED Recessed lights

Answer (score -1):

Of course, it's best to just re-wire everything. But, I presume you don't care where the circuit's initially powered and want to come off that basement switch.

Well then, you're in luck. You'll need to branch off of one of the existing and will be remaining 3-ways' Travelers to power the other lights and their switches. The Travelers are always on, the switches are what switches.

This will minimize your fishing and new hole making. You'll have some cutting and pulling of the old wire into the new switch locations (if you're SUPER LUCKY). I don't suspect you are, so expect to be thwarted by staples holding the old wire tight and having to do some new wiring.