# Can I use #14 wire pigtails on a 20A circuits?

Tags: electrical

I’ve used 12 gauge wire and 20 amp breakers in my basement.

They go into a shallow box and the 12 gauge is difficult to work with.

Can I drop to 14 gauge in the receptacle boxes and pigtail the connection ?

Comment: "Difficult" is relative - as you do more work you'll get used to  squooshing 12-gauge inside receptacle boxes.   Don't much with the existing gauge wire.

Comment: Six #12 wires in a shallow box is no fun regardless of experience. It's a good question. I'm fairly sure there's a duplicate to be found, though.

Comment: Have you tried using *stranded* THHN wire for the pigtails, instead of solid NM-leftovers?

Comment: If everything is wide open then install a deeper box. 14 gauge wire is not permitted on a 20A circuit.

Comment: **No**.........

Answer (score 17):

You can drop to #14 gauge **but you must change your breaker to a 15 amp breaker**. Can you replace the shallow box with a deeper one and stay with the #12?. You really don't want to lower the circuit rating in a basement. Still pigtail the connection but use the #12. It might make fitting everything back into the box easier. You could also use a box extender to get a bit more room. Some food for thought: outlets in an unfinished basement need to be GFCI protected.

Comment: The answer is no - I would make that clearer.

Answer (score 12):

Only if you also change the breaker to 15A.

Answer (score 10):

Options in this case:

**1) Put the GFCI device somewhere else.**  E.G. at the breaker.   Many people do not realize this, but any GFCI device can provide GFCI protection to anything connected to it.  This means you can place the GFCI in a more practical location, and use plain receptacles at this site, which will mean your box is not so crowded.

**2) If surface mount, use bigger boxes.**  If you are trying to fit a GFCI or other bulky "special device" in a 1-gang steel "Handy-Box", that will indeed be difficult.  Switch to one of these:

- a 2-gang (4" x 4") steel box.  If it is Decora (large rectangle opening), use a short **mud ring** to come out to a normal 1-gang or 2-gang opening (that is to say, do not use a **domed cover**).
- A 4-11/16" (120mm) square steel box with a domed cover or mud ring.

**3) Use a box extension.**  You can get these in a variety of sizes and styles. For flush mounted boxes, one of my favorites is a Legrand Wiremold Surface Conduit Starter Box.  (which is actually not for this, but it works).

**4) Use stranded wire.**  Yes, #12 solid can be a little bit stiff.  However they also make stranded wire which is amazingly flexible.  You need to buy this in a form called THHN (single-conductor).  THHN must be contained within a junction box or conduit; it is not legal for use "loose inside walls" like cable is. But most shops will sell you THHN by the foot at a low price. It is made in both solid and stranded; be sure to buy stranded.

- Stranded wire works fine on wire nuts mixed with solid; as always you crank down very hard (but you should be doing that normally). It must never be used with jab-in "backstabs" on switches and receps (which are #14 solid, only).  It can be challenging for the novice to twist the strands tightly enough and into a J-hook to get it to fit on screws; you mustn't permit the strands to scatter. However it works great with "Screw-and-clamp" type outlets (where it goes in a slot beneath the screw, and you tighten the screw to clamp).  The vast majority of GFCIs provide 2 screw-and-clamps under each screw.

**5) Change the breaker to 15A**, *and mark the #12 wire/cable in the service panel to indicate there is #14 wire in the circuit*.  Otherwise "the next guy" will think you under-breakered the circuit and slap in a 20A.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do what you are suggesting. 12awg wire is for 20 amp circuits, 14awg is for 15 amp circuits. Using 14awg anywhere in the circuit path of a 20amp breaker will result in excessive heating and probably start a fire.

Comment: It'll only start smoking when the circuit's heavily loaded...but yeah, the general gist is correct :)

Comment: I'd state it the other way around, but w/e. First word: *No*, +1.